# PHP, Database: Preserving and searching strings with whitespace

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following scenario:

I am storing user input that MAY contain whitespace. The problem is, when I do a `SELECT` from the database (`MySql`), it does not find a match. If I strip the whitespace, the search on db works, but the strings are all messy looking if I store them this way.

How can I properly store strings (with whitespace) in the database `AND` correctly do `SELECT` statements that will find those stored strings??

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I am working with now:

```
$filename = "This is a string with white space";
//being stored in the db like this

$trim_string = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $filename);
//search db as Thisisastringwithwhitespace
```

Still finds no match though?

Comment: Store the unedited and search by the `trim()`'d version?

Comment: Clever! :P Another option would be to use regular expressions.

Comment: By whitespace, do you mean trailing spaces? Please provide examples.

Comment: mostly space in between words, but there might be the possibility somebody inputs a string with trailing spaces

Comment: So, you're storing 'This is a string' in the database and expect it to match 'Thisisastring' in a search?

Comment: Final update: After a couple of hours of debugging, it was more than the problem stated. I found a couple of logical errors in my code, and once I fixed those, all went well. Thank you all for all the help.

Comment: then please update the question, so the storing was not the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the user would know the entire string, I would go with Blake suggestion of using TRIM() in the Mysql query, if you want the partial search, and want it fast, I would create a secondary table with the words and another one for the position where appears in the strings, something like this :

```
Word( id, string )
WordInString( id, source_string_id, word_id, position )
```

The search would be in 2 steps :

```
1. get the words ids
2. get from WordInString the top list with greater number of Words hits, and show the options to the end user.
```

Hope it helps !